# JSF 2.0; myfaces with JavaScript disabled; CommandButton has no class in rendered page

Tags: jsf, myfaces

that's my first post here on stackoverflow.
I'm searching around a while for solving my problem. 
In my JSF-Page I got a `<h:commandButton>` with styleClass set and on web.xml I disabled JavaScript (JavaScript isn't allowed on the hole page).

On then rendered page on Firefox, the CommandButton will not change its style, because the "class"-tag is missing.
If I turn on JavaScript, everything works fine and also the "class"-tag for the CommandButton is on the rendered page.

What I'm doing wrong or is this a bug in myfaces 2.1?

Best wishes and many thanks.

Tobi

Comment: I'd report it to the MyFaces guys over there on apache.org.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Can you give me the link, so I can follow the issue?

Comment: Uh no, I have not reported it. It was just a suggestion that you should report it. Maybe you overlooked or misunderstood the `'d` part? It stands for "would". You can read it as "If it were me, I would report it ... "

Comment: Ah yes, ok... I really misunderstood ;-) I read it as "I had". I would report the problem to apache.

Comment: For your intereset: that was a bug in myfaces and it is already solved in 2.1.7 (nightly, latest build)

Comment: Okay, I reposted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in MyFaces. Report it to MyFaces guys over there on apache.org.

Comment: yes, it was! i reported the bug already and it is fixed since 2.1.7 (nightly build)